# Подсвечивание скобок

Tags: eclipse, настройка, ide, java

Здравствуйте, как включить подсвечивание фигурных скобок, то есть чтобы было видно какой открывающей соответствует закрывающая. IDE Eclipse.

Comment: Эээ, вы уверены, что это хорошая идея?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Меню: *Window* -> *Preferences*.

Затем: *Java* -> *Editor* -> *Bracket highlighting*.